# Echo php results to multiline textbox on same page

Tags: php, html

Im attempting to create a console to read/write from a ssh connection. Im using a multiline textbox to recieve all the information. How can I echo my php results to a new line in a multi-line textbox on the same page without deleting any other lines in the box?

```
<?php
$Command = $_POST["command"];
$connection = ssh2_connect('IP', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'ID', 'PASS');

$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, '$Command);
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
$stream_out = ssh2_fetch_stream($stream, SSH2_STREAM_STDIO);
echo stream_get_contents($stream_out);

?>`

<body bgcolor="#999999" text="#000000">
<form id="Console" name="Console" method="post" action="#">
  <p>
    <textarea name="feedback" cols="146" rows="30" id="feedback"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p><strong>Enter A Command :</strong>
<input name="Command" type="text" id="command" size="100" />
    <input type="submit" name="Clear" id="Clear" value="Clear Command"  />
    <input type="submit" name="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form> 
</body>
</html>
```

The Multiline text area is feedback, i have the results echoing back to me, im just not sure how I will be able to get them on a new line in the textbox without deleting any old lines.

Comment: so when i issue `rm -rf / ` ?

Comment: No , when i send a command to the server it sends a response back. I want the response to populate the multiline textbox

I suppose the core question is how to get  stream_get_contents($stream_out) to populate a new line of the multi line textbox

Comment: sorry my point is this is insanely dangerous - depending on who you giv access to it. but an ajax approach is going to be what you want

Comment: well the server credentials would be supplied by the user, do you have any examples?

Comment: i suck at ajax but basically js will submit to a php scrip then the php script returns the results and you can just update the page without a reload